# Add Filter to selector in Acumatica Mobile

Tags: acumatica

We have currently added the Warehouse/Bin Transfer to the Acumatica Mobile to allow users to do bin transfers via the Mobile versus using Acumatica.

We have added the QtyAvailable to the From and To Bin selectors in the with the SelectorContainer statement. However is there a way to filter out only those records for the item instead of showing all bins/location. This filter would only be on the from location. The to location would still show all locations.

Answer (score 0):

To show only bin/locations with **Qty. Available greater than 0**, you should extend Where condition for LocationAvailAttribute decorating the INTran.LocationID field:

```
using PX.Data;
using System;

namespace PX.Objects.IN
{
    public class INTransferEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<INTransferEntry>
    {
        [PXRemoveBaseAttribute(typeof(LocationAvailAttribute))]
        [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
        [LocationAvailCst(typeof(INTran.inventoryID), typeof(INTran.subItemID), 
            typeof(INTran.siteID), typeof(INTran.tranType), typeof(INTran.invtMult))]
        public virtual void INTran_LocationID_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
        {
        }

        public class LocationAvailCstAttribute : LocationAvailAttribute
        {
            public LocationAvailCstAttribute(Type inventoryType, Type subItemType, 
                Type siteIDType, Type TranType, Type InvtMultType)
                : base(inventoryType, subItemType, siteIDType, TranType, InvtMultType)
            {
                var attr = _Attributes[_SelAttrIndex] as PXDimensionSelectorAttribute;
                var dimAttr = attr.GetAttribute<PXDimensionAttribute>();
                var selAttr = attr.GetAttribute<PXSelectorAttribute>();
                var select = selAttr.GetSelect();
                select = select.WhereAnd<Where<INLocationStatus.qtyAvail, Greater<Zero>>>();
                var newAttr = new PXDimensionSelectorAttribute(DimensionName,
                    select.GetType(), typeof(INLocation.locationCD),
                    new Type[]
                    {
                        typeof(INLocation.locationCD),
                        typeof(INLocationStatus.qtyOnHand),
                        typeof(INLocationStatus.qtyAvail),
                        typeof(INLocationStatus.active),
                        typeof(INLocation.primaryItemID),
                        typeof(INLocation.primaryItemClassID),
                        typeof(INLocation.receiptsValid),
                        typeof(INLocation.salesValid),
                        typeof(INLocation.transfersValid),
                        typeof(INLocation.projectID),
                        typeof(INLocation.taskID)
                    });
                _Attributes[_SelAttrIndex] = newAttr;
                newAttr.ValidComboRequired = attr.ValidComboRequired;
                newAttr.CacheGlobal = attr.CacheGlobal;
                newAttr.DirtyRead = attr.DirtyRead;
                newAttr.DescriptionField = attr.DescriptionField;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the custom LocationAvailCstAttribute added on the INTran.LocationID field, Location selector will show only bins/locations, for which current Inventory Item Qty. Available is greater than 0:
[image]

Comment: i understand how this could be acomplished in Acumatica. My question is how would this be done in the Acumatica Mobile product. By making the changes in Acumatica, would the logic somehow work in the mobile product as well. Just want to be sure about your post. I was pretty clear on how to do this in the Acumatica Code. Just was wondering on doing the same in Acumatica Mobile.

Comment: Since Acumatica mobile app works as a player, every time you need to change something inside business logic (this is one of those scenarios), you have to make changes via an extension class. Those changes will be applied to both web browser and mobile apps.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had already made some changes. I will verify they are working properly in the Mobile product.